# ActiveRecord::Base.transaction の最中に return すると何が起こる?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Ruby において、 block の中の break や return は、その block が定義された時の method call をただちに終了させる効果があると理解しました。

この場合ふと次のことが気になりました：

1. block の中で break や return が呼ばれる可能性によって、 block を yield する method は、どうがんばっても、 ensure 的に最後に実行する処理というものは記述できない。
2. rails における `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` は block を引数(厳密にはちがうけれども)にとって、その中身を transaction の文脈で yield している(はずだ)と理解できるけれども、しかし 1. を考慮すれば、開始した Transaction を確実に終了 (commit もしくは rollback によって) させるようなコードは transaction メソッドの中では記述できない

そうすると次の疑問が発生します。

#### 質問

- rails において、 `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` の block の中で直接、 break や return を実行した場合においては、その transaction メソッドの Database に対する操作はどのようなものになりますか?可能性として以下がありうるかな、と思っています。

  - commit される
  - rollback される
  - transaction が開始され、その commit/rollback のどちらも行われない中途半端な状態になる
  - <s>宇宙の法則が乱れて、</s> active record の動作が未定になる
  - ...

Comment: 類似の質問：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18810/%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B6%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%A7%E9%81%B7%E7%A7%BB%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B%E5%85%B7%E4%BD%93%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%81%AF%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

どうやら、自分が思い違いをしていた様子です。 block 中の break/return であっても、それによって外へ抜けられてしまう ensure 節はたしかに確実に実行されている様子です。なので、 transaction も、そのように ensure でもって確実に実行されるコードを実行し、 transaction の管理を行っているのではないか、と推測しています。

```
class Foo
  def test_return
    yield_with_ensure do
      return
    end
    puts "returning test_return"
  end

  def test_break
    yield_with_ensure do
      break
    end
    puts "returning test_break"
  end

  def yield_with_ensure
    begin
      yield
      puts "after_yield"
    ensure
      puts "hoge ensured!"
    end
  end
end

puts "testing return"
Foo.new.test_return

puts "testing break"
Foo.new.test_break
```

#### 出力

```
testing return
hoge ensured!
testing break
hoge ensured!
returning test_break
```